# C++ Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'system.dll' - When I'm not trying to open it

Tags: c++, windows, dll, linker-errors

I'd like some help debugging my project

Working on Windows10, Microsoft Visual Studio.
I'm getting the following error:
`Error  LNK1104 cannot open file 'system.dll'   KoKo    C:\LocalEnvironment\NewAgent\KoKo\KoKoAgent\LINK    1`

Background:
A week ago I played around with `system.dll` functionalities.
At the time I've added a copy of `system.dll` file in the same folder with the executable generated by VS.
Changed solution Configuration Properties -> Advanced -> Common Language Runtime Support: "Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)"

What I've tried:
Now I've changed the configuration back to "No Common Language Runtime Support"
I've removed the `system.dll` file from my project's folder.
I've checked solution configuration "Linker" -> "Input" -> "Additional Dependencies" does not contain "system.dll".

I've searched throughout my solution configurations and did not find "system.dll" anywhere.

Yet, MSVS is still sent out to use system.dll, and I can't figure out why.

I'd really appreciate any help figuring out where my problem is.
I've searched for this error everywhere and did not find any clue whatsoever.

Comment: tried a clean build?

Comment: @AlanBirtles
Doesn't work :\

Comment: Even though I don't need "system.dll" I even tried adding its path to Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.
And I still receive the same error.

Comment: Eventually what I did was just open a new solution and recreate all my files.

Now I don't receive this error.